# unsure with SQL Select query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables relationship called tblCluster, tblServer, and tblDatabase. Server is under Cluster and Database is under Server. PK in tblCluster is ClusterName. Pk in tblServer is ServerName and FK is ClusterName. PK in tblDatabase is DatabaseName and FK is Servername. If I want to see all ServerName and DatabaseName under/from ClusterName is Cluster5. Should I write query like

```
SELECT tblCluster.ClusterName, tblServerName.ServerName, tblDatabase.DatabaseName 
FROM tblCluster 
JOIN tblServer 
ON tblCluster.ClusterName = tblServer.ClusterName 
INNER JOIN tblDatabase 
ON tblServer.ServerName = tblDatabase.ServerName 
WHERE tblCluster.ClusterName = Cluster5;
```

If servername is found even database is empty I still want it display result table of  with datbasename null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` - this is typically the solution for such requirements. [Look here](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php) for a more detailed explanation containing some examples.

Comment: Thank, that is what I thought it sould be LEFT Join.